# JavaFX classpath definition to include WiX config file on Windows

Tags: ant, javafx, wix

On the last few weeks I've been working on a JavaFX Application to deploy for both Unix and Windows. At the moment, I'm trying to customize the install scripts/ config files.

On MacOS I simply included the script to the class path using `<property>` on my ANT build file like this:

```
<property name="classpath" location="package/macosx/App-dmg-setup.scpt"/>
```

But when I try to do the same on Windows, doesn't work (continues using the default config file). I've already tried absolute path, `env.CLASSPATH` instead of `classpath`, and some other alternatives, with no success.

Thanks a lot ;)

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Ok sorry this question, actually I was inadvertently changing the basedir variable. The correct definition should only be:

```
<path id="fxant">
    <filelist>
        <file name="${java.home}\..\lib\ant-javafx.jar"/>
        <file name="${java.home}\lib\jfxrt.jar"/>
        <file name="${basedir}"/>
    </filelist>
</path>

<taskdef resource="com/sun/javafx/tools/ant/antlib.xml"      
    uri="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant"
    classpathref="fxant"/>
```

Without another (re)definition.

Once again, thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem, and configured the ant build like in your example. But this does not work for me. Its saying `Using default package resource [WiX config file]` How do I get ant build to use my custom wxs file?